# Flexible table of images

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, tabular

I'm looking for a way to present N images in a table / tabular form.
The catch is, it needs to handle window resize or different resolutions and re-arrange itself.
I'm able to use JQuery in my project, but if possible to avoid it would be better of course.

Comment: what do you mean by window resize? Do you want the images to become smaller, the number of images in a row or the width of table columns?

Comment: Have you looked at http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: @boisvert, yes. the number of images in a row

Comment: @JusticeErolin, this kind of solution I'm looking for, but I don't want to use 3th party code, but rather creating a simple solution and specific solution for this cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images will naturally reflow when their parent element resizes.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/dwbHi

Now if you want to have the spacing between the elements evenly distributed, Flexbox can help you out:

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/iHGCd

```
.gallery {
  margin: -5px;
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  flex-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
@supports (flex-wrap: wrap) {
  .gallery {
    display: flex;
  }
}

.gallery img {
  margin: 5px;
}

<div class="gallery">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" /><!--
    --><img src="http://placehold.it/200x120" /><!--
    --><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" /><!--
    --><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" /><!--
    --><img src="http://placehold.it/200x140" /><!--
    --><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" /><!--
    --><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" /><!--
    --><img src="http://placehold.it/200x130" /><!--
    --><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" /><!--
    --><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" /><!--
    --><img src="http://placehold.it/200x100" /><!--
    --><img src="http://placehold.it/200x90" />
</div>
```

Current browser support:  Chrome, Opera, IE10.  http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Alternately, you could use CSS Columns (same markup as above):

http://jsfiddle.net/qeZaZ/

```
.gallery {
    -webkit-columns: 250px;
    -moz-columns: 250px;
    columns: 250px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you said that you would rather not use JQuery but just off the top of my head you may want to look at using Twitter Bootstrap, it will allow you do this exact thing straight out of the box with the fluid grid system in a really short amount of time and I believe you can download a custom build of Bootstrap if you want a stripped down version that only handles the grids.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem

Comment: I'd rather not to use 3th party frameworks/toolkit. I am familiar with the benefits of using a framework of this kind, but I'd rather create a simple/specific solution for this cause.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float` and some `@media` to achieve the result, I've prepared a small fiddle with a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sandro_paganotti/A6n9n/1/

The key is in the CSS:

### CSS

```
img{ width: 33%; display: block; float: left; }

@media all and (max-width: 450px){ img{ width: 50% } }
@media all and (min-width: 550px){ img{ width: 20% } }
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but that's not what I meant. I don't want to resize the images, but make the images re-arrange in the new window size